# Multiple insert into SQL Server 2008 via Ado.Net 3.5 and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have a collection of data. I need to insert these records into SQL Server 2008. I also need to maintain transaction, so that if one insert fails, I need to rollback all the changes done.

Can some one suggest a best way to do this? I use .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all about TransactionScope and System.Transactions.

Comment: I have about 300 items in my collection. Should i make 300 calls to the DB, all under Transaction Scope.? Can i proceed this way? Ur comments?

Comment: Yes, you can. It will work. If you find it runs too slow for your taste, you can consider bulk mechanisms. Usually for 300 items it's not worth the trouble (unless you're inserting 300 items once a second...).

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a transaction using your `SqlConnection` object's [BeginTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566.aspx) method. This will return an `SqlTransaction` object that you need to keep track of.

When all of your items have been successfully inserted into the database, you will call Commit on the transaction object.

If an exception is encountered during your processing, you will need to call Rollback on the transaction object.

Roughly speaking, the code is:

```
SqlConnection conn;
// Create and open your connection here

SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
try {
   // Perform your inserts

   trans.Commit();
} catch(Exception ex) {
   trans.Rollback();

   // Report the exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending of wheather you are using ADO.NET/plain SQL you can use [bulk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) insert, or, if you are using Linq-to-SQL you can try using [LINQ Entity Data Reader](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/LinqEntityDataReader) to insert large amounts of data at once.

By using bulk insert each batch is copied to the server as one transaction. If this fails, SQL Server commits or rolls back the transaction for every batch.